# Seiberg Duality Applications

Tags: supersymmetry, quantum-chromodynamics, duality

I am interested in why people are interested in [Seiberg duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiberg_duality)? Can it be used for something? Does it (or may it) correspond to any 'real world' physics? I don't have enough background to understand the details and I would like to know if it is worth the effort.

Comment: While your question(s) is reasonable, your last sentence is quite off-putting honestly. You state`...I would like to know if it is worth the effort'. If you are interested in something go study it, if not then go find something that you are interested in. My point being as you start doing research and looking into advanced topics you will constantly confronted with this question ' is it worth it' - only you can answer that for yourself.

Comment: @DJBunk: I agree with DJBunk, it's quite off-putting. If the topic is interesting, even perhaps in a highly abstract mathematical sense, I think it merits attention $\mathbf{\mathrm{regardless}}$ of whether it has any 'real world' applications.